# UITableView not display contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to populate a UITableView in my viewcontroller (it is a delegate of UITableView)

The code below is something I've found online. I've made some changes so that I didn't need a UITableViewController in order to use it. However since I changed it, I am unable to figure out how to get the text to print in the cells. Before changing the code to allow my ViewcController subclass to be a delegate of UITableView. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: empty UITableView]

I have checked and the XML is parsing correctly. When the code reaches the `if (marrXMLData.count != 0)` in the `startParsing` method, `marrXMLData` is greater than 0 (8 being specific, the correct and total number of items in my XML)

code is from: http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xmlparsing-with-nsxmlparser-tutorial

.m is below

```
DisplayTableViewController

@synthesize marrXMLData;
@synthesize mstrXMLString;
@synthesize mdictXMLPart;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startParsing];
}

- (void)startParsing{
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.xml"]];
    NSXMLParser *xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:fileData];
    [xmlparser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlparser parse];
    if (marrXMLData.count != 0) {
        [self.myUITableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Content"])
        marrXMLData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
        mdictXMLPart = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;{
    if(!mstrXMLString)
        mstrXMLString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [mstrXMLString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName     namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;{

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"url"]){

        [mdictXMLPart setObject:mstrXMLString forKey:elementName];

    }
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])

        [marrXMLData addObject:mdictXMLPart];
        mstrXMLString = nil;

    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section{
    return [marrXMLData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[marrXMLData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[[marrXMLData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

EDIT:

After playing with it some more this method is not being called

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In the example code it is being called, but I'm not sure where. (Sorry, I am very new to iOS)

Comment: Your question is too vague to be answerable. "I am unable to figure out how to get the text to print in the label." What does that mean? What text? What label? Do you get the correct number of cells? Do you get contents in the text label but not the detail text label, the detail text label but not the text label, or neither? What code triggers your XML parsing and populates your XML data array?

Comment: This code assumes that `[xmlparser parse]` runs and finishes before the `[self.myUITableView reloadData]` , first of all make sure that `self.myUITableView reloadData` is called after parsing finish, either with nslog or breakpoints, then make sure `marrXMLData` array has objects in it. A quicjk but bad fix would be moving your `[self.myUITableView reloadData]` to the end of  didEndElement `(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement`

Comment: Hello @DuncanC I made some edits to explain better. I am trying to populate cells in a UITableView. The label would be in the cell

Comment: @u.gen marrXMLData does have objects in it! I edited my question to explain more of what I see when I run the code.

Comment: @Airagale What is your cell identifier in storyboard set to?  What is the value of `[marrXMLData count]` at runtime?

Comment: @Frankie the identifier is "cell", at runtime `marrXMLData` is 8

Comment: You say cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called. What about `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection`? If none of those are being called then you don't have the data source of the table view set up correctly.

Comment: @DuncanC neither of those are being called. How can i set up the data source correctly?

Comment: You should definitely read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your example is not at the very least neither complete nor verifiable: your source is incomplete (we don't actually know what your class inherits from — you tell us it inherits from a `UIViewController` but there's nothing to add a `UITableView` anywhere, nor is there anything to set the `UITableView` `delegate` or `dataSource` — is this set via a storyboard?). Also, what would you not use an `UITableViewController` in this case?

Comment: @jcaron I'm not using a UITableViewController because I do not want the list to be full screen when the app runs. I did give it a read! Thank you. Sometimes I am not sure how to ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your table view's delegate and/or dataSource links are not connected. If you set up the table view scene in IB (Interface Builder) then you just control-drag from the table view onto the view controller.

Comment: When you say control + drag  onto the view controller, do you mean creating an IBOutlet for the UITableView in the .h file?

Comment: No. If you select the table view and the correct inspector (I forget what it's called and I'm not at my Mac. Connections inspector?) then you'll see an item for the delegate and for the data source. You need to add a entries in your view controller's interface indicating that it conforms to the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols, and then drag from the data source and delegate connections onto the view controller.

Comment: I was able to find what you were talking about one the IB. I tried clicking and dragging bother the datasource and the delegate to the view controller but it would not link. Instead I linked it programmatically in my viewDidLoad function [myUITableView setDelegate: self]; and [myUITableView setDataSource: self];

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Note that you can embed a UITableViewController in anothe view controller using a container view and an embed segue. Then you get the advantages of a table view controller and it doesn't have to fill the sceeen.

Comment: That is what I have done- and why I was having such a problem. The example I used made use of the UITableViewController and I wanted a ViewController with a UITableView inside it. That example does not set the datasource or the delegate.